# Office side automation from SSIS

Tags: sql, ssis

PLease help me out.
I am currently migrating DTS 2000 packages to SQL 2005 version. I have a package which has a VB script in it. The job of this VB script is to download data from AVAYA server and update some templates. Post which it will select specific cells in the excel templates and update some more templates and run a stored procedure to further update a table.

I know that this can be replaced by SSIS scripting. But I have come to know that office side automation is not recomended anymore from SQL server.

So what is the best possible solution. This is a strict requirement that I update those excel templates from SSIS.

Comment: Best possible solution is to not deal with Excel. It's a cantankerous pain in my backside and it's automatic manipulation can make you old before your time. That impractical advice aside, what are you looking for in an answer? SSIS can dump rows into Excel in a tabular manner straight out of the box. As you state, you need to update specific cells so the OOB won't work. Is this question how to accomplish that or something else? Do you have a specific question in mind or just want the generalities?

Comment: My question is if I have to get data from specific cells and update data to specific cells, what is the best possible way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw this [question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/43461/ssis-how-can-i-write-to-a-specific-cell-in-an-excel-sheet) over on dba.SE and it seemed an interesting approach. By installing the ACE OLEDB driver, not a full blown Office install, you can use any of your familiar DML (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE) statements to modify values in Excel. I've used this approach to query Excel like a table before but never thought to try to modify the contents.

After installing the driver, you simply create an OLE DB Connection to the Excel resource and then use an Execute SQL Task to fire off your updates. Syntax to add the value `DOB` to cell D2 on Sheet1 would be

```
INSERT INTO [Sheet1$D2:D2] VALUES ('DOB')
```

Other examples from the wordpress article

```
INSERT INTO [NameOfExcelSheet] VALUES('firsttextcol', 2, '4/11/2009');
-- [I assume First Column is char field, 2nd col is integer, 3rd is Date]

DELETE FROM [NameOfExcelSheet] Where secondintcol=2;

UPDATE [NameOfExcelSheet] SET secondintcol = 3 where firsttextcol = ‘firsttextcol’;
```

### References

- http://www.winautomation.com/forum/updating-excel-through-sql-statement
- http://yoursandmyideas.wordpress.com/2011/02/05/how-to-read-or-write-excel-file-using-ace-oledb-data-provider/
- http://bidn.com/blogs/KeithHyer/bidn-blog/2475/updating-a-single-excel-cell-using-ssis